# C# I am trying to move a file from one directory, where I wont know what the name of the file is, to a new directory

Tags: c#, file, directory

I have the below throwing an exception: System.ArgumentException: 'Empty file name is not legal.
Parameter name: sourceFileName'

```
    public bool ArchiveFile()
    {
        int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\company\Archive\IN\InvoiceTest\Inbox\").Length;
        DirectoryInfo diFileCheck = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\company\Archive\IN\InvoiceTest\Inbox\");
        foreach (var fi in diFileCheck.GetFiles())
        {
            string strSourceFile = Path.GetFileName(@"\\company\Archive\\IN\InvoiceTest\Inbox\");
            string strDestination =Path.Combine(@"\\company\ArchiveIN\InvoiceTest\Archive\", strSourceFile);
            File.Move(strSourceFile, strDestination);
        }
        if (fileCount==0)
        {
            string strMessage = "No file found in directory: \n\n";
            MessageBox.Show(strMessage, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
           return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What did you **expect** to happen with no Filename? What would be the logical thing for **you** to happen if someone answers the question "Wich file?" with Silence?

Comment: where do I define filename?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is here:

```
foreach (var fi in diFileCheck.GetFiles())
{
    string strSourceFile = Path.GetFileName(@"\\company\Archive\\IN\InvoiceTest\Inbox\");
    string strDestination = Path.Combine(@"\\company\ArchiveIN\InvoiceTest\Archive\", strSourceFile);
    File.Move(strSourceFile, strDestination);
}
```

Your `fi` is a `FileInfo` object, but you are not using it. Instead of using `Path.GetFileName`, use `fi.Name`.

See [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This gives me non-invocable member FileInfo.Name cannot be used like a method.

Comment: @Joe you need to use it as a property, e.g. string strSourceFile = fi.Name;

Comment: Ah yes! Thanks! 
On the File.Move line I get 'Could not find the file C:\dev'
Had a google and updated NuGet packages but its still showing

Comment: @Joe you will need to append the filename to the original directory path that you were enumerating.

Comment: I think thats my problem though, I can append the file name but I want to be able to pick up any .csv files from the original directory as I might not know the file names going forward - is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

This reads all files from a source directory, and moves them to a target directory:

```
var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles("Source"); // get file paths from folder 'Source'

foreach (var filePath in filePaths)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath); // get only the name of the file

    var targetPath = Path.Combine("Target", fileName); // create path to target directory 'Target' (including file name)

    File.Move(filePath, targetPath); // move file from source path to target path
}
```